# How to install GraphicsMagick with PNG support on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, libpng, graphicsmagick

If you naively follow [the steps on the GraphicsMagick website](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html), after running `./configure`, you end up with no PNG support:

```
checking for PNG support ...
checking png.h usability... no
checking png.h presence... no

PNG               --with-png=yes        no
```

This makes for a pretty useless GraphicsMagick instalation.

How can I enable PNG support? Libpng seems to be installed already, but not detected:

```
> $ sudo yum install libpng
> Package 2:libpng-1.2.49-1.12.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install the `libpng-devel` package, in addition to just `libpng`:

```
sudo yum install libpng-devel
```

Then when you run `./configure`, everything will work out as you'd hope:

```
checking for PNG support ...
checking png.h usability... yes
checking png.h presence... yes

PNG               --with-png=yes        yes (-lpng12)
```

<Rant>This is why everything should be available in packages that clearly specify their dependencies and are easily installed with package managers, instead of requiring arcane knowledge of compilation prerequisites.</Rant>

Comment: Domenic, how in the world did you know that libpng-devel had to be installed?

Comment: I think I'd seen the `-devel` suffix once before for something, and since there was all this compiling and linking going on, I thought maybe the development pieces might be needed. I didn't have much to go on to lead me in that direction... But thankfully it turned out to be the right direction.

Comment: I did that and it worked for me just right.  So thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how to go about finding about the full list of packages available for an AWS AMI instance?

Comment: I don't, sadly... Sounds like a good question for this funny site I know called StackOverflow! ;)

Comment: i can't find this package (libpng-devel) anymore. :S